# Regex to match a number not in a list

Tags: regex

I've been trying to create a regex to match a number that is not in a list, but haven't been able to figure it out. It might not be possible.

For example, given the list "1,3,13,17,21,30" I would like the regex to match "40" (which is not in the list), but not match "3" which is in the list.

Does anyone know how I might be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the only text that will be in the string to search for is the actual number only, simply anchor to the beginning and end of the string, and exclude the numbers from the list using negative lookahead:

```
(?!^1$|^3$|^13$|^17$|^21$|^30$)^\d+$
```

This regex **can** be reduced a little, but I think in this form it is more obvious You're excluding matches from a list, improving readability.

If the string has other text, however, you might try to anchor it to a separator character(such as a space or simply \b)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking to use Negative Lookahead as follows:

```
\b(?!(?:1[37]?|21|30?)\b)\d+\b
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zN8rI7/2)

Comment: You don't need the additional non-capturing group inside; a negative lookahead won't capture its results. In addition, all your possible results need word boundaries after or else it won't be able to match longer numbers (like 132). The result looks like this: `\b(?!1[37]?\b|30?\b|21\b)\d+\b`

Answer (score 0):

Just use two separate regexes in your language of choice, like:

```
/\d/ && ! /(1|3|13|17|21|30)/
```

...or something similar, probably you'll need anchors in each depending on the string you're matching against (which, btw, you should provide when asking questions like this on SO).

Comment: `11` won't pass the test.

Comment: Yeah, lazy questions get lazy answers. As I said, he needs anchors, but without knowing his target string it's impossible to guess what those would be.

Comment: How's it a lazy question? I'm trying to find a regex that matches a number that is not in the list "1,3,13,17,21,30". This may not be achievable though.

Comment: actually it almost works, just by changing `/(1|3|13|17|21|30)/` to `/^(1|3|13|17|21|30)$/`

Comment: Like I said, it needs anchors. But without knowing the target string you can't tell what those anchors need to be, perhaps `^$`, perhaps `\b`, perhaps `\D` - who knows.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know in what context you would use this functionality, but if you know the list contains all digits and the one you want to filter is digits too, why don't you use a set?

in python(assuming your `list` is stored in `l`):

```
s = {int(s) for s in l.split(',')}
if int(some_num_txt) in s:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

it's way faster and more intuitive than regex.

Comment: Yes, if I could use code this would be much easier. Unfortunately, I need to enter the regex into a web site control panel. :(

Answer (score 0):

edited: should work now

```
\b(?!(1\b|3\b|13\b|17\b|21\b|31\b))\d+\b
```

Comment: `300` doesn't pass the test. Thanks for trying though. :)

Comment: @SimonBingham Read the comment I posted on hwnd's answer. There just need to be word boundaries after each possible number you don't want to match.